# Check if id is in column

Tags: mysql

I have an table with elements, I can link those elements to a page. To do that I've made a table, pageRelations. So now I want to get al the elements that aren't linked to the page.

```
SELECT `elements`.*, `pageRelations`.`pageId`, `pageRelations`.`elementId`
FROM (`parts`, `pageRelations`)
WHERE `pageRelations`.`pageId` = '1'
AND `parts`.`id` NOT IN (pageRelations.relationId)
```

The results aren't correct.

Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0):

this says get all elements where the element is not found in the page relations table.

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM elements AS e
WHERE e.Id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT elementId 
    FROM pageRelations
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You're probably looking for something like this.

```
SELECT e.*
FROM elements AS e
LEFT JOIN pageRelations AS pr
ON  e.Id = pr.elementId
WHERE pr.elementId IS NULL
```

Comment: hmm, this isn't working for me. I don't get any results. Thanks for your response

Comment: I'm not looking for a NULL value but for the elements that aren't linked

Comment: With LEFT JOIN a null value in left table would indicate there's no matching element, so no link.

Comment: Also, there was a syntax error in the query. I used `p.elementId` instead of `pr.elementId`

Comment: this amounts to saying select all elements where e.id is null... which is probably the primary key thus impossible.

Comment: Of course David. Except I use such queries in everyday work, and they do what I want them to do. You will find examples like this all over internet including SO. Here's example: http://www.freeopenbook.com/mysqlcookbook/mysqlckbk-chp-12-sect-6.html